# Create SP for inserting data from a table to a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, temporary-tables

I have a table that has 1 record where one field may have 2 values separated by commas (in that cases I have to create 2 records with those values separated in 2 row and the other field values are the same). To do these I had to make some selects but how can I do the stored procedure to do that in a easier way??? When there are 2 telephone number separated with ',' with the first SELECT I insert to table3 the row with the phone number before the ',':

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Telefono, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Telefono, 0) - 1) AS Telefono
    ,Nome,Indirizzo,CAP,Comune,Prov
INTO table3
FROM #table1
WHERE Telefono LIKE '%,%'

INSERT INTO table3
--the record with the phone number after the [,]
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Telefono, CHARINDEX(',', Telefono, 0) + 1, LEN(Telefono)) AS Telefono
    ,Nome,Indirizzo,CAP,Comune,Prov,Fax
FROM #table1
WHERE Telefono LIKE '%,%'

INSERT INTO table3
--insert all the remaining rows
SELECT DISTINCT Telefono
    ,Nome,Indirizzo,CAP,Comune,Prov,fax
FROM #table1
WHERE Telefono NOT LIKE '%,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you start thinking about a solution, try to evaluate if your requirements make sense.

Is it really the best solution to create duplicate rows if multiple phone numbers exist or would it be better to create a new table `PhoneNumbers` with a foreign key?

And splitting data can be done more elegantly in the tool that loads the data into the database. If you *have* to do it in SQL, the solution depends on the database system you use.
For instance, here is a solution for SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5493510/1595345